# What kind of mushrooms are these?

Tags: identification, fungus, mushrooms

I've noticed these mushrooms growing in my backyard today. They are likely thriving on dead grass that my lawnmower has been leaving behind. Can anyone identify them? I am located in the Houston, Texas area.

[image: Mushroom(2)]
[image: Mushroom(1)]

Comment: I usually don't pay attention to mushrooms unless they seem to be damaging something.

Comment: @jmusser I'm not really worried about them, just curiosity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like [panaeolus foenisecii](http://www.mushroomexpert.com/panaeolus_foenisecii.html). Very common in lawns this time of year.